# Oracle SQL Developer 0913 - too many values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to return the MINIMUM VALUE and the MAXIMUM VALUE in my PRICE table(the field is the val_price).
What is the problem with this query?

```
select des_price, val_price from price
WHERE val_price IN
(SELECT MIN(val_price), MAX(val_price) from price);
```

The error message is:

00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:
*Action:

If I try with just one value in the inner select everything works fine, but with multiple values I don't know why is not working.
This example works fine with 2 values in the follow inner select:

```
UPDATE price SET val_price = val_price * 1.05
WHERE des_price in('NORMAL','RELEASE');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select two columns from `sub-query` when you are using only one column in `Where` clause

Try this way

```
SELECT des_price,
       val_price
FROM   price
WHERE  val_price IN (SELECT Min(val_price)
                     FROM   price
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT Max(val_price)
                     FROM   price);
```

or

```
SELECT des_price,
       val_price
FROM   price
WHERE  ( val_price, val_price ) IN (SELECT Min(val_price),
                                           Max(val_price)
                                    FROM   price)
```

Comment: It's working with your code... do you have any special advice with a page ow a good book about Oracle SQL to understand why mine was wrong? Thank you.